# How to get ::before element of DOM via CSS (CSS3)?

Tags: css

I'm trying to get the element and set some styles to it, but it's my first time and I can't achieve it. I also can't set id or class to the element, because it's dynamically generated. I'm searching for the easiest solution and believe, that you guys will help me with this simple question.

[image]

Here is my **HTML:**

```
<md-list class="no-paddings" flex="100">
    <md-list-item flex="100" ng-repeat="adGroup in adsGroupsAndKeywords track by $index">
        <md-menu>
            <div layout="row" layout-align="space-between center">
                <div ng-click="AdsGroupsCtrl.openMenu($mdOpenMenu, $event)">
                    <h6>
                        {{ adGroup.name }}
                    </h6>
                    <md-chips
                            ng-click="call($event)"
                            md-on-remove="AdsGroupsCtrl.removeKeywordFromGroupOfAds($chip);"
                            ng-model="adGroup.keywords"
                            readonly="true"
                            md-removable="true">
                        <md-chip-template>
                            <em>{{$chip.keyword}}</em>
                        </md-chip-template>
                    </md-chips>
                    <md-divider></md-divider>
                </div>
            </div>
            <md-menu-content width="4">
                <md-menu-item>
                    <md-button ng-click="AdsGroupsCtrl.addToCurrentGroup($index)">
                        Добавить в данную группу
                    </md-button>
                </md-menu-item>
                <md-menu-item>
                    <md-button
                        ui-sref="app.expansionOfSemantics.adsList(
                            {
                                campaignsId: capmpaignId,
                                adId: adsGroupsAndKeywords[$index].id,
                                regionIds: adsGroupsAndKeywords[$index].regionIds,
                                keywords: keywords
                        })">
                        Сознать новую группу на основе текущей
                    </md-button>
                </md-menu-item>
            </md-menu-content>
        </md-menu>
    </md-list-item>
</md-list>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are required to paste a minimal example of the code that shows the problem here, not a picture of it unless you are willing to accept a picture of the fix. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _"can't set id or class?"_ If the id or class that is generated dynamically and is already in the CSS you do nothing, styles will be applied. Do you know how to write a CSS selector? Please elaborate.

Comment: @hungerstar, I mean that I can't set my own class or id, there are many other elements with such classes and I cant use them to set my own styles

Comment: @Rob, I have updated the question and posted HTML code

Comment: How to get `::before` using CSS? ... Like this `.classname::before { ... }`

Comment: @LGSon, but can I somehow start from `md-list-item` (I'll set my own class for this element) and get the child's `div` (the div with classes *md-no-style*, *md-list-item-inner* and *md-ink-ripple*)?

Comment: @CommercialSuicide you do know that [**you can override the styles**](https://jsfiddle.net/wt2Lncck/) applied with those ids and classes right? Or apply your own custom classes to override existing styles. From your comments it sounds like you need to find a _Intro to CSS Tutorial_.

Comment: Yes, you can start from `md-list-item`. May I suggest you take a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Selectors

Comment: OK guys, but I'd like to sharpen the focus, that this `div` is **not in my HTML**, it's dynamically generated by angular-material, so I can't just set my own classes to it, right? If not, please, tell me how to set my own classes to this div

Comment: @CommercialSuicide but you do know what the markup of that HTML will be and the ids and classes applied to it right? If so, it's not any different than if you had supplied the HTML yourself and everything we've mentioned still applied. The CSS that is included on a page doesn't really care if it was there on page load or after an Ajax request or created by some other means. If a CSS selector matches, styles are applied.

Comment: @hungerstar, yes, I just trying to add my own class to this element

Comment: @CommercialSuicide so your actual question is _"How to add class to Angular Material?"_ I'd try searching that.

Comment: @hungerstar, actually yes, something like: *How to add class to dynamically generated elements by Angular Material*

Comment: I've found a number of SO and other articles that tell you how to add a class to Angular Material. So the answer is out there. I think you're getting a little hooked on the _"dynamically generated"_ part. Also, look into how to add class in Angular app.

Comment: @hungerstar, can you please share some resources? I'd like to look them through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code I am not certain which your pseudo-element is. But in general you select pseudo-elements with `::before` and `::after`. 
The pseudo-elements are created by the `content`-property, the `::before` and `::after` pseudo-selectors as the name implies just select the location.

```
::before{...} or ::after{...}
```

(select all pseudo elements on the website that are located as first or last child inside their parent element respectively)

```
.className::before{...}
```

(selects the pseudo-element that is located as first child inside the element with the class="className")

```
.className::before{content: '';}
```

(::before selects the first spot inside the element with the class="className" but its the content-property that creates the pseuod-element)

Comment: @CommercialSuicide this is exactly what LGSon mentioned in comments. Which is also basic CSS.